# Restrict inheritance of Interfaces

Tags: c#, interface

Is there a possibility to restrict the inheritance of interfaces to several classes?
Like only classes of the Type UserControl can inherit from my IUserControlStyle interface. I would like to enforce project conventions through that.

I know that it's possible to limit generic types, but I don't if it's possible to apply the same on "normal" interfaces

Comment: No, you can't limit a type from implementing an interface.

Comment: I would not advice it anyway - why should an *interface* know about the implementing *classes*?  It just generates dependency-cycles and complexity

Comment: of course you could use an abstract base-class that derives from `UserControl` instead ;)

Comment: I am using a Interface which should be applied only to UserControls. It would be nice if there would be a possibility to enforce this, that I don't have to check manually if the Interface was accidentally used in a Form.

Comment: Maybe restrict in run time? `if (!(this is UserControl)) throw new NotAUserControlException();`

Comment: I guess you want to enforce this in code (like the generic constraint you mentioned) - why not just look for the interface **and** `UserControl` there?

Answer (score 0):

Because it seems as if there would be no solution which enforces that only UserControls implement my IUserControlDefaultStyle interface, I need to do it in Runtime via System.Reflection in the Program.cs .

```
            List<Type>l=typeof(IUserControlDefaultStyle).Assembly.GetTypes().Where(x => !x.IsSubclassOf(typeof(UserControl)) &&x.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IUserControlDefaultStyle))).ToList();
            if (l.Count > 0)
            {
                l.ForEach(x=>Console.WriteLine(x.Name+"   is abusing IUserControlDefaultStyle"));
                throw new Exception("IUserControlDefaultStyle was abused");
            }
```

this is not a nice but a working solution. It's ugly because you get the Exception after you made the application run, and not already when you're coding. If anyone knows  a better solution, let me know.

Answer (score -1):

Well you cant restrict Interface inheritance or implementations. But you can always use attributes for that case. 
For example you can create an ImplementsInterfaceA class-type attribute and use it on the classes that will be implementing, or in some form, be related to a given Interface.

And after that, with reflection, you can get only these classes which have the ImplementsInterfaceA  attribute, and take care of the implementation.
This way you can control which classes can implement your interface.

Comment: you should add how you can do this with *attributes* at least - as it is, it's just a comment

Comment: how does this enforce anything? where is the code? What do you mean by *fetch*? Why can you not simply *fetch* the classes implementing `IUserControlStyle` instead of having an artificial attribute on top?

Comment: thought so - so again: why can't you just use reflection to *get all classes implementing `IUserControlStyle`*? How would that solve the OPs problem? - sorry but this is just not an answer and will not get one

Comment: that's possible, but not nice. I'll post it as answer if there'll be no better solution..